# Finding density of $Y = \alpha \tan (\pi X)$ when $X \sim U(-1,1)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

I tried the following:

$$ P[Y \leq y] = P[X \leq \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(\frac{y}{\alpha})]$$

By looking plugging $x = \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(\frac{y}{\alpha}) $ in  the CDF of $X$,  I "guessed" that the edges $-1$ and $1$ mapped to $-\infty$ and $+\infty$, and also obtained:

$$ F_{Y} (y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\arctan(\frac{y}{\alpha}) + \frac{1}{2}$$

Since $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ and we're evaluating $\tan(\pi x)$, the function actually maps onto the real numbers *twice*, so I multiply by two:

$$ F_{Y} = \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(\frac{y}{\alpha}) + 1$$

And differentiating I get the pdf:

$$f_{Y}(y) = \frac{\alpha}{\pi}\frac{1}{\alpha^2 + y^2}$$

I believe the result is right, but I'd like to know if there's a less clumsy way of obtaining it. I'm not sure that the cumulative function method was well suited for this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: You are right. And I can't think of an easier way.

Comment: You seem to have correct intuition, but your solution needs to be brushed up to be a mathematically correct one. For instance, in the first formula, we cannot deduce $X\leq\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{y}{\alpha}\right)$ because $$g(x):=\alpha\tan(\pi x)$$ is not injective on the support $(-1,1)$ of $X$. Instead, you may use the graph of $g$ to deduce the correct condition for $X$ (which will depend on whether $y>0$ or $y<0$) and then you may proceed as usual. In general, this approach yields the formula of the form $$ f_{g(X)}(y) = \sum_{x:g(x)=y} \frac{1}{|g'(x)|}f_X(x). $$